# passing default parameter C++

Tags: default-parameters

I have a method void setVal(msgA, functPtr* = NULL, paramTypePtr = NULL );

So there are two different code paths which would like to use the method. 
1) Would like to pass in a message and NULL functPtr and a valid paramTypePtr. 
2) Would like to pass in a message and valid functPtr and NULL paramTypePtr.

So can I call for case 1) setVal(msg1,NULL,&param1);
and for case 2) setVal(msg2,funct1Ptr,NULL);

Are the above 2 valid calls?

PS: Someone else wrote the framework which provides the above method.I understand it should have been designed a bit different in a way there aren't 2 parameters with default values. But trying to see if I can use it without changing the framework using the above calls.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameters in C++ can be written as follows.

```
void DefaultParamCheck(int x = 0, int y =100);
```

Here, *DefaultParamCheck* is your function name. And the value of first parameter will be by default 0 and value of second parameter will be by default 100.

You have written this function **void setVal(msgA, functPtr* = NULL, paramTypePtr = NULL )**. When you are passing **NULL** to the second or third parameter then giving default argument is meaningless.

In case 1, you can call the function by setVal(msg1, NULL, (paramTypePtr)&param1) because it will take the default NULL for second parameter. Otherwise, you will get error.

In case 2, you can call the function by  setVal(msg2,funct1Ptr) here third parameter will be NULL by default. You don't need to call it by NULL.

Comment: So are you implying that in case1 if I call setVal(msg1, (paramTypePtr)&param1) ; that the compiler will deduce the second parameter to be NULL. Is this compiler specific or C++ std defined?

Comment: In fact I just tried it by removing the NULL in case 1 and when I compiled got a "error: no match for call to .." type error. In case 2, I agree the NULL is not needed and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, You are right. The first case wouldn't work here.